# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist. BUT there's not even any reference to LoginController made in the first place

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, breeze

I am trying to learn laravel and is using version 10. I used breeze for the login auth. Everything was fine and I was working on my blades when the login,register,logout suddenly stopped working with this error.

I did not make any changes in the routes, I tried everything including that one where I have to put  `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`  inside the RouteServiceProvider.php but nothing worked. Has anyone ever encountered this issue?

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});


require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';

Auth::routes([
    'verify' => true
]);
```

and my auth.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('register');

    Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('password.request');

    Route::post('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('password.email');

    Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('password.reset');

    Route::post('reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('password.store');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('verify-email', EmailVerificationPromptController::class)
        ->name('verification.notice');

    Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', VerifyEmailController::class)
        ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
        ->name('verification.verify');

    Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware('throttle:6,1')
        ->name('verification.send');

    Route::get('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
        ->name('password.confirm');

    Route::post('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store']);

    Route::put('password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])->name('password.update');

    Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->name('logout');
});
```

Comment: [Auth::routes uses Auth\LoginController](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-auth-tips), it looks like. Do you have that controller?

Comment: `php artisan route:list` -> lists all the routes.

Comment: @aynber I don't have it but it used to work before. I am sure I have not deleted anything

Comment: @francisco it also gives a bunch of errors looking for Auth\LoginController and Auth\RegisterController which I don't have and is not used anywhere.

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` if it cleans

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake of mixing breeze and laravel ui while exploring. Apparently, I used

```
Auth::routes([
  'verify' => true
]);
```

Which is something that should be used in laravel ui, also uninstalled it and settled with breeze